# Is it possible to use a serialized property for associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have something similar to this:

```
class Bucket < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :droplets, Array #of IDs
end

class Droplet < ActiveRecord::Base
  #...
end
```

Since a single `Droplet` can belong to multiple `Bucket`s (the real problem is a bit more complex), is there a "rails-way" of achieving something similar to the following:

```
#in some action
@bucket = Bucket.find(47)
@droplets = Droplet.find_all_by_id(@bucket.droplets)
```

so that one can access `Bucket#droplets` where every element of the array would be a `Droplet`?

Comment: Couldn't you just add an instance method `droplets` to `Bucket` which returns `self.class.find_all_by_id(droplets)`?

Comment: if you set it up right, meaning with a has_many and a belongs to in the models you can just get all the droplets of a bucket with Bucket.find(47).droplets. if you want i can type it out with some more code in an answer

Comment: @rik.vanmechelen Wouldn't that mean a `Droplet` could only `belongs_to` a single `Bucket`? The only other possible solution I can think of is using a third table to keep track of all the associations (which I'd rather not do).

Comment: @shioyama I could, but that's essentially the same as what I use. I was wondering if there's a built-in functionality for it! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a many to many relationship.
It is really recommended to do this with 3 tables.
if you dont want this, you have to keep the array in the sql, in which case you will lose some rails functionality and have to do it as you described yourself with

```
@bucket = Bucket.find(47)
@droplets = Droplet.find_all_by_id(@bucket.droplets)
```

if you want to do in a cleaner way do:

```
class Bucket < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :droplets
end

class Droplet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :buckets
end
```

you will need a migration:

```
# in migration
def change
  create_table 'buckets_droplets', :id => false do |t|
    t.column :bucket_id, :integer
    t.column :droplet_id, :integer
  end
end
```